# what is the difference between a gitlab runner and a gitlab agent?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I'm new to Gitlab and Kubernetes and I'm wondering what the difference between a Gitlab runner and a Gitlab agent is.

On gitlab it says an agent is used to connect to the cluster, run pipelines, and deploy applications.
But with a regular runner you could just have a pipeline that invokes `kubectl` to interact with the cluster.
What is possible with an agent that isn't with a runner using `kubectl`?

Comment: I would make an educated guess that an agent is a manager or broker, and the runner is what is actually used to do the actual pipeline tasks. So in theory you could have one agent, but multiple runners, and those runners could be setup to run on specific node setups.

Comment: So when I'm having multiple nodes in the cluster an agent would manage all of them while the runner would only manage the server it is running on?

Comment: I believe the _agent_ would be responsible for spawning the _runners_ into the cluster.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I believe I understand :)
So if you want the reputation you can put it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The answers below I think are satisfactory, they go into more details so I would recommend accepting one of those :)

Comment: They are just copy pastes of the documentation, using so many buzzwords, that I didn't understand anything and chose to ask here in the first place. Yours is an actual explanation

Comment: I have added an answer with a few more details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GitLab Agent (for Kubernetes) is the way GitLab interacts with the Kubernetes cluster (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/) and is used to allow GitLab to generate GitLab runners which are like Jenkins agents (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/). Consider it like a broker or manager in this case. The agent would spawn the runners inside the cluster with the configuration you have setup.

For example, in my case, I have a node-pool dedicated specifically for gitlab runners. These nodes are more expensive to run, since they're higher-spec than the standard nodes used by the rest of the cluster, so I want to make sure only the GitLab runners spawn on there. I configure the Runner to have a node selector and toleration pointing at that specific node pool so the cluster scales up that node pool to put the runner on it.

The agent itself provides way more functionality than just spawning runners, but your question only asks about the GitLab agent and Runner. You can review the pages I've linked if you would like to find out more.

Answer (score 5):

from docs
GitLab Runner is an application that works with GitLab CI/CD to run jobs in a pipeline.
you should install GitLab Runner on a machine that’s separate from the one that hosts the GitLab instance for security and performance reasons.

so GitLab runner is designed to be installed on a different machine to solve security issues and performance impact on a hosted machine

The GitLab Agent for Kubernetes (“Agent”, for short) is an active in-cluster component for connecting Kubernetes clusters to GitLab safely to support cloud-native deployment, management, and monitoring.

The Agent is installed into the cluster through code, providing you with a fast, safe, stable, and scalable solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed run `kubectl` commands from Gitlab CI... but for some people or organisations, the Kubernetes cluster is not directly network accessible from Gitlab Saas or from your Gitlab instance. Because of NAT, network segmentation, private network, whatever...

The main purpose of the Agent is to be installed in your Kubernetes and establish a network connection (reverse tunnel) to your Gitlab instance or Gitlab SaaS so that Gitlab CI can use this tunnel and send Kubernetes commands/API to your private Kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0):

> The GitLab Agent (for Kubernetes) is the way GitLab interacts with the Kubernetes cluster

But that means it needs to be compatible with your GitLab instance.

Fortunately, with [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#view-gitlab-agent-for-kubernetes-version-in-the-ui) (March 2022):

> ### View GitLab agent for Kubernetes version in the UI
>
> If you use the GitLab agent for Kubernetes, you must ensure that the `agentk` version installed in your cluster is compatible with the GitLab version.
>
> While the compatibility between the GitLab installation and `agentk` versions [is documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/#upgrades-and-version-compatibility), until now it was not very intuitive to figure out compatibility issues.
>
> To support you in your upgrades, GitLab now shows the `agentk` version installed on the agent listing page and highlights if an `agentk` upgrade is recommended.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/repository.html#view-your-agents) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/340882).

---

Plus, with [GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#api-to-retrieve-agent-server-kas-metadata) (July 2022)

> ### API to retrieve agent server (KAS) metadata
>
> After we released the agent for Kubernetes, one of the first requests we got was for an automated way to set it up.
> In the past months, [Timo](https://gitlab.com/tuxtimo) [implemented a REST API](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#rest-api-for-the-agent-for-kubernetes) and extended the GitLab Terraform Provider to [support managing agents](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/cluster_agent) in an automated way.
>
> The current release further improves management of the agent specifically, and of GitLab in general, by introducing a `/metadata` REST endpoint that is the superset of the `/version` endpoint.
>
> The `/metadata` endpoint contains information about the current GitLab version, whether the agent server (KAS) is enabled, and where it can be accessed. This change improves upon the previous functionality, where you had to put the KAS address in your automation scripts manually.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/metadata.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/357032).

---

And, compare to a regular agent, you now can with [GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#install-the-agent-for-kubernetes-using-extra-volumes-in-the-helm-chart) (July 2023):

> ### Install the agent for Kubernetes using extra volumes in the Helm chart
>
> The `agentk` component of the agent for Kubernetes requires a token to authenticate with GitLab.
>
> Previously, you could provide the token as-is, or as a reference to the Kubernetes secret that contains the token. However, you might operate in an environment where the secret is already available in a volume, and prefer to mount that volume instead of creating a separate secret.
>
> From GitLab 16.2, the GitLab agent Helm chart ships with this added feature thanks to a community contribution from [Thomas Spear](https://gitlab.com/tspearconquest).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/#customize-the-helm-installation) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-agent/-/issues/33).