# gitlab runner and gitlab agent on gitlab on-premissse instance

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Most of the doubts I had, I was able to clarify in the post below.

[what is the difference between a gitlab runner and a gitlab agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70752766/8442925)

But one remains. I have an on-premise gitlab installation and I configured the gitlab agent linked to my on-premise k8s cluster.

When the project is pushed, in the deploy stage, it is waiting for a runner. Is it necessary to have the runner and the agent together?

I thought that CI/CD was only possible with the agent, but it seems to me that the runner is needed. If that's the case, I don't see why I should have both, because with the runner I can already deploy correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to have the runner and the agent together?

No. The agent and runners are mostly exclusive components.

You only need a runner for GitLab CI/CD, generally. Runners are required to run CI pipelines/jobs.

The agent is only required if you want to use GitLab's builtin operation utilities for deploying/managing workloads on a k8s cluster.

> I don't see why I should have both, because with the runner I can already deploy correctly.

If you already have your own workflow for deploying to your k8s cluster and you don't want to switch to using GitLab's utilities/workflows (like [Flux+GitOps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/gitops/flux_tutorial.html)) for k8s management, **you don't need the agent at all.**

Comment: @systech And if I wanted to use only the gitlab agent for my CI/CD, would that be possible? Could you explain this better?